# Manga where main character wakes up in a forest and encounters two students

Tags: story-identification, manga

The manga is black and white.

The main character woke up in a forest and killed some monsters (I can't remember what the monsters are). I also think they were trying to understand magic in that world, then saw two students. The first student was eager to try some new spells(?) and the second student was trying to tell the other that they may get in trouble for entering the forest.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @NeedHelp - When you say "students," do you mean like Japanese high school students? And was the main character transported to this world from Japan as well? Also, did he know the students beforehand, or was this the first time he met them?

Comment: What happens with the students? Does he go on travels with them? Kill them?

Comment: The students are from a magic academy and the chapter ends there cuz it was only 2 chapters when i last read it, nothing much is known in mc's story but I think mc was reincarnated there

Comment: I think the monsters were goblins

Comment: Do you remember when you read this?

Comment: What I was thinking of is *Meiou-sama ga Tooru no desu yo*. There's 3 students, not 2, and they all die at the end of the 2nd chapter, so if you're certain they don't die then that's not it.

Comment: My description is a bit off but Meiou-sama ga Tooru no desu yo is the manga im looking for,thanks @qazmlpok

Answer (score 2):

As confirmed in the comments, this is *[Meiou-sama ga Tooru no desu yo!](https://kitsu.io/manga/meiou-sama-ga-tooru-no-desu-yo-comic)*.

> Osamu, a young man who died at a young age due to an incurable illness. His second life was to drift as a "spirit (demon)" in an unknown world! Osamu, who is hated by humans and unreasonably deprived of his "life," hopes that he "does not want to die anymore." At that time, he gained the power of "life-sucking" that feeds on the vitality of others. In addition, he will resist the approaching "death" by using the science that he continued to learn on the bed in the previous …

The story opens with the protagonist, a sickly child in a hospital, dying and reincarnating in another world as some type of spirit. He is attacked by goblins, but unharmed, and ends up absorbing their essence, becoming stronger.

[image: The goblins]

Shortly after that, some students come into the forest and discover the goblin corpses. They're there to practice magic in preparation for some exams, and show the protagonist that magic exists.

[image: Magic practice; main character watching from a tree]

Three months later, the students return, use magic to detect nearby monsters, discover the protagonist, and attack him like any other monster. He's stronger than them and kills them, absorbing their strength as well, and flees the area.